# Cannot access page in OAuth2.0

Tags: java

I am trying to customize the login page.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/demologin")
      .loginProcessingUrl("/oauth/authorize").permitAll();
}
```

Check the demo of login here:

OAuthServer&Client/spring-security-auth-server/src/main/resources/templates/demologin.html

This error is displayed when I try to access the page.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Feb 04 11:40:18 IST 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No message available

I am running it on my localhost server here :- http://localhost:8001/auth/demologin

Comment: what if you go to http://localhost:8001/demologin ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you configured `.loginPage("/demologin")` but you try to login at `http://localhost:8001/auth/demologin`.

According to the response of 404 `/auth/demologin` seems to be not existing.